# Array of node pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class Node {
  Node **ptr;
  int size; //  current size of the node

Node::Node() {
  ptr = new Node *[MAX + 1];
}
void Tree::insert(int x) {
   Node *cursor = root;
   // some code...
   cursor->size++;
   cursor->ptr[cursor->size] = cursor->ptr[cursor->size - 1];
```

I am confused what cursor->ptr[cursor->size] = cursor->ptr[cursor->size - 1] line is doing conceptually. What is the cursor->ptr[cursor->size] points to if it was not use before during the logic of the code above. I am assuming we have array of pointers but what they point to when we create them? Can you explain what this line is doing?
TIA!

Comment: To remove a level of indirection I would change `Node** ptr` to `std::vector<Node*> ptr`. I think your confusion may be the fact that there are two levels of pointers, one is the dynamic array and the other is each individual Node in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Before you are doing anything, implement your Descructors such that you do not run into any memory leak. This is a must have when you are dealing with pointers within a class.
And about the question. Your class is constructing a dynamic list of double pointers pointing to single pointers. These pointers in the list are currently pointing to other Node pointers. To really understand this logic I would recommend you to look up how linked list or double linked list are working.
Maybe this might help you https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/linked-list-c-plus-plus

Comment: Thanks, is my understanding correct? I am not sure why we need dynamic list of double pointers, can we create dynamic list oof single pointers and it will work similarly here?

Comment: As far as I am concerned it should be sufficient. But I would still recommend it to you to try it out!